# Airflow doesn't "see" that the underlying Kubernetes pod completed

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, kubernetespodoperator

We are using a hosted Airflow 1.10.2 in Google Composer 1.7.5 to launch jobs via the `KubernetesPodOperator` (tasks that will be run in a Kubernetes pod inside a worker cluster)

There has been several occasions in which the Kubernetes pod itself successfully completes, but Airflow doesn't "see" that the pod has completed (it doesn't get the memo), so Airflow *thinks* the pod is still running and doesn't move onto the next task.

We are planning to move to Composer 2 with Airflow 2.1.4, which I'm fairly confident it manages pods and communication with Kubernetes better, but...

... is there a "quick" tweak we can do? Even a link on how to start investigating would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Composer 2, your environment’s cluster scales automatically. Extra workloads that you run using `KubernetesPodOperator` scale independently from your environment. You can do the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart#airflow-2) then add the the [`KubernetesPodOperator` configurations](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/use-kubernetes-pod-operator#:~:text=KubernetesPodOperator%20configurations).

Comment: Can you provide more information, please? Can you determine a pattern when this is happening? Maybe when the KubernetesPodOperator executes tasks for long period of time? Also, it can be useful to see the parameters and values you are passing to the operator.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, @Alvaro. Unfortunately, we haven't been able to identify a pattern. Most of the times Airflow _"does get the memo"_  and tasks are properly marked as "successful". But in (seemingly random) occasions it gets "stuck". It might just be some resource exhaustion in the cluster?

Comment: @BorrajaX, that is shame. The only thing I can think of is that for some reason the task is mark as zombie. It might be good to add a timeout as a parameter to the operator to retry after X amount of time. At this point you should already know what is the expected time for the task.